# How to add a new line in a file without overwriting current line?

Tags: java

I currently have.

```
public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Formatter("Data.text");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("File not created");
    }
}
```

.
.
.
.

.

.

```
public void addRecords(){
    x.format("%s %s %s %s", first(), last(), ID(), num());
}
```

But after I run the file, it overwrites the data each time?

Comment: This is similar to or a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.io.File)) will truncate the size of the file to 0. Use [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)) instead. Then you can use the [PrintWriter's printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to do the same thing.